# Can I pass a Class type as a procedure parameter

Tags: delphi, parameter-passing

I want to create a function that returns all the names of a certain class as a string list. Based on the previous solution / question I tried to this code with no success

```
function  GetClassElementNames (TObject ) : TStringlist ;
var
  LCtx : TRttiContext;
  LMethod : TRttiMethod;
begin
  try
    LCtx:=TRttiContext.Create;
    try
      // list the methods for the any class  class
      for LMethod in  LCtx.GetType(TObject).GetMethods do
        result.add(LMethod.Name);
    finally
      LCtx.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      result.add (E.ClassName + ': ' +  E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `TClass` for that, which `TRttiContent.GetType()` expects anyway.

You are also not allocating the Result before filling it.

Try this:

```
function GetClassElementNames(Cls: TClass) : TStringlist ;
var
  LCtx : TRttiContext;
  LMethod : TRttiMethod;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  try
    LCtx := TRttiContext.Create;
    try
      for LMethod in LCtx.GetType(Cls).GetMethods do
        Result.Add(LMethod.Name);
    finally
      LCtx.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Result.Add(E.ClassName + ': ' +  E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

```
var
  Methods: TStringList;
begin
  Methods := GetClassElementNames(TSomeClass);
  try
    ...
  finally
    Methods.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to pass in an object instance instead of a class type, you can wrap `GetClassElementNames()` like this:

```
function GetObjectElementNames(Object: TObject): TStringList;
begin
  Result := GetClassElementNames(Object.ClassType);
end;
```

With that said, it is not a good idea to return a new TStringList object.  It is better, and more flexible, if the caller allocates the TStringList and passes it to the function to fill in, eg:

```
procedure GetClassElementNames(Cls: TClass; AMethods: TStrings);
var
  LCtx : TRttiContext;
  LMethod : TRttiMethod;
begin
  try
    LCtx := TRttiContext.Create;
    try
      for LMethod in LCtx.GetType(Cls).GetMethods do
        AMethods.Add(LMethod.Name);
    finally
      LCtx.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      AMethods.Add(E.ClassName + ': ' +  E.Message);
  end;
end;

{
procedure GetObjectElementNames(Object: TObject; AMethods: TStrings);
begin
  GetClassElementNames(Object.ClassType, AMethods);
end;
}
```

```
var
  Methods: TStringList;
begin
  Methods := TStringList.Create;
  try
    GetClassElementNames(TSomeClass, Methods);
    ...
  finally
    Methods.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can I exlude all the default functions like Create
Free
InitInstance
CleanupInstance
ClassType
ClassName
ClassNameIs
ClassParent
ClassInfo
InstanceSize
InheritsFrom
MethodAddress
MethodAddress
MethodName
QualifiedClassName
FieldAddress
FieldAddress
GetInterface
GetInterfaceEntry
GetInterfaceTable
UnitName
UnitScope
Equals
GetHashCode
ToString
SafeCallException
AfterConstruction
BeforeDestruction
Dispatch
DefaultHandler
NewInstance
FreeInstance
Destroy
I only need my used defined  procedures

Comment: Use `TRttiType.GetDeclaredMethods()` instead of `TRttiType.GetMethods()`. That will return only the methods that are explicitly declared in the specified class and ignore any inherited methods that are not overridden in the class. If you want to ignore constructors and destructors, you can check `TRttiMethod.IsConstructor` and `TRttiMethod.IsDestructor` before calling `TStringList.Add()`.